# How do I get the current date in elm?

Tags: elm

I'm trying to figure out how to get the current date in elm in version .17. I see that they added a Date module to .17 but I haven't found any examples on how it's used. Has anyone figured out how to do this?

Edit: 
In trying to retrofit this solution, I hit another stumbling block. I'm trying to trigger setting the date and then calling another Msg to do something else. But I'm still getting {} for a date.

```
import Html.App as App
import Html exposing (..)
import Time exposing (Time)
import Task
import Date exposing (Date)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)

type alias Model =
  {currentDate : Maybe Date}

type Msg =
  SetDate (Maybe Date)
  | TriggerDateSet

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    SetDate date ->
      ({model | currentDate = date}, Cmd.none)
    TriggerDateSet ->
      (model, now)

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
  [ div []
    [ button [onClick TriggerDateSet] [] ]
  , div [] [ text <| "(Optional) time at program launch was " ++ toString model ]
  ]

now : Cmd Msg
now =
  Task.perform (always (SetDate Nothing)) (Just >> SetDate) Date.now

main : Program Never
main =
  App.program
    { init = ( Model Nothing, now )
    , view = view
    , subscriptions = always Sub.none
    , update = update
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want the `now` Task or the `every` Subscription from [Time](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Time#now).

Here's an example using the former to initialise the model with the current time.

```
import Html.App as App
import Html exposing (..)
import Time exposing (Time)
import Task


type alias Model = 
  Maybe Time


type Msg = 
  SetTime (Maybe Time)


update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update (SetTime time) _ = 
  (time, Cmd.none)


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div [] [ text <| "(Optional) time at program launch was " ++ toString model ]


now : Cmd Msg
now = 
  Task.perform (Just >> SetTime) Time.now


main : Program Never
main =
  App.program 
    { init = ( Nothing, now ) 
    , view = view
    , subscriptions = always Sub.none 
    , update = update
    }
```

Comment: I was trying to get the current date. Using your example, I replace all references to time with date and it return {}. I'm thinking it might be easier to port to js to get it.

Answer (score 3):

+1 for answer from @SorenDebois. You can refactor to date. Either by doing a

```
myDate = Date.fromTime timeFromMaybe
```

Or by using Date everywhere in the code. Below is the complete example (adapted from the other answer).

```
import Html.App as App
import Html exposing (..)
import Date exposing (Date)
import Task


type alias Model = 
  Maybe Date


type Msg = 
  SetDate (Maybe Date)


update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update (SetDate date) _ = 
  (date, Cmd.none)


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div [] [ text <| "(Optional) date at program launch was " ++ dateString model ]


dateString : Model -> String
dateString model =
  case model of
    Nothing -> "No date here"
    Just date ->
      "the date is "
      ++ (toString <| Date.dayOfWeek date)
      ++ " "
      ++ (toString <| Date.day date)
      ++ " "
      ++ (toString <| Date.month date)
      ++ " "
      ++ (toString <| Date.year date)

now : Cmd Msg
now = 
  Task.perform (Just >> SetDate) Date.now


main : Program Never
main =
  App.program 
    { init = ( Nothing, now ) 
    , view = view
    , subscriptions = always Sub.none 
    , update = update
    }
```

Comment: I was able to combine your answer with the answer above and got to work! Thanks!

Comment: Task.perform changed and now the correct syntax is: `Task.perform (Just >> SetDate) Date.now`